# How does Adobe Acrobat determine the scaling for fit-printing?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, scaling, margins, acrobat-pro-dc

Due to printer margins, outer page elements may not be printed when attempting to print a document at 100% scale. When one chooses the "fit" scaling option instead, Acrobat chooses a scale such that everything prints fines except for a small size reduction (assuming you're using the same paper format as the pdf). However, this scale seems arbitrary and *varies* for different pdf files, i.e. I had files where the scale was 97% and others where it was 94%. So my question is

> Given identical paper size pdfs, why is the scaling of the fit-print option so different?

Comment: probably it does not only considers paper types of document & printer, and non-printing area of printer, but also the borders already set in the document. If your printer can't print on 5 mm wide border of papers, but your document already doesn't have anything to print there, then there is no need for reduction,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not too mistaken, Acrobat scales the bounding box around the contents so that it fits into the printable area. That would explain the differences you notice.

Also, not all printers have their printable area in the same proportions as the paper. This also has an effect on the scaling.